# Nested window.addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is this working...

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    alert('Function #1');
});

window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    alert('Function #2');
});
```

... and this is not?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
    alert('Function #1');
    window.addEventListener('load', function (){
        alert('Function #2');
    });
});
```

I'm looking for a way to load (jQuery get) and render information asynchronously.
e.g.

```
get(resource_1)
check if resource_1 has been fetched with interval, then render resource_1

 if resource_1 has been rendered
   get(resource_2)
   check if resource_2 has been fetched with interval, then render resource_2

   if resource_2 has been rendered
     get(resource_3)
     check if resource_3 has been fetched with interval, then render resource_3

     ...
```

Comment: Because `load` has already fired when the inner `load` event handler is added to the `window`, so nothing happens.

Comment: Also note that the `load` event has nothing to do with the pattern you outline in the last code snippet. I'd suggest using promises/callbacks for that

Comment: In general, you rarely want to add event listeners inside other event listeners. If the first event fires multiple times, you get multiple copies of the second listener.

Comment: I'm now in callback hell, but yes, callbacks ARE the solution.